# Praise: Gotta love Open Sans

Tags: discussion, design, praise

I just wanted to say that after a couple of days looking around, I'm **loving** the alterations to the type for the site.

The alteration to the size slightly, the letter spacing and the use of Open Sans (which I've always loved) rather than Helvetica Neue has made overall reading a much more pleasant experience.

See the difference here (other beta site on left)....

[image]

Nicely done!

Added a Praise tag.. it's needed :)

Comment: Seconded! Now it is SO that hurts my eyes :)

Comment: I also love the new type changes! But, disaster, loads of my answers are now full of orphaned words from where I'd previously tweaked the wording to get the key points onto one or two neat lines.... `:-D` I should have seen that coming!

Comment: Ya I edited my thanks in the launch to mention this but its worth having its own. So incredibly wonderful!

Comment: Even orphans need a place to live.

Comment: +1 to what you have presented using screenshots here. I love to use SAN-SERIF fonts as well, but Open Sans, since is being used everywhere, is not that very cool to me now. Since our firm has the Adobe Typekit in box for us to design, I love to use the various San-Serifs present there. Especially Proxima Nova. Mate if you can, please also try Novacento, I'm sure u'll love it as well. :)

Comment: Say goodbye, this will soon be no more.