# How do you turn off the new skin?

Tags: discussion, site-redesign

How do i turn off the new skin? Its horrible, you cant even read the headings anymore, body text is sort of passable.

Who has time to make a user script that will actually, you know fix the design?

Comment: So long as they keep pretending fixed-size fonts and fixed-width containers that max out without updating their font size, measure, leading, and letterfit depending on whether we're talking display/titling fonts versus text/body fonts versus caption/tiny fonts as being "responsive", they still don't understand what responsiveness is supposed to be based on how real people really use the web on high-resolution screens these days. Until and unless they hire someone who truly understands how these affect typography, they're just wasting time and money cranking out ever-more-unhelpful mis-designs.

Comment: Problem with the webpage is that its hardly responsive at all. It dont work on the phone well and it kinda works on a desktop. But the old one did both better, on phone and desktop.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To get the Open Sans font back, add this as a user style. You can either use an extension, or your browser's built-in capabilities. Google will tell you how to do it.

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans');

html, body, h1, h2, h3, h4, p, a, ul, ol, li, input, textarea {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans !important;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

p {
    line-height: 1.5em;
}

#question-header .question-hyperlink {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans !important;
}
```

If you want the red colours back on your buttons, links, tabs, etc, add this:

```
.s-btn__primary,
.s-btn__filled,
input[type="submit"]:not(.s-btn),
input[type="button"]:not(.s-btn),
button:not(.s-btn),
.button,
a.button,
a.button:visited,
.btn,
.hero-box.double-panel .panel.white .btn {
    border-color: #b03340;
    box-shadow: none;
    background: #ea4a5a;
    color: white;
}

.s-btn__primary:hover,
.s-btn__filled:hover,
.s-btn__filled:active,
input[type="submit"]:not(.s-btn):hover,
input[type="button"]:not(.s-btn):hover,
button:not(.s-btn):hover,
.button:hover,
a.button:hover,
a.button:visited:hover,
.btn:hover,
input[type="submit"]:not(.s-btn):focus,
input[type="button"]:not(.s-btn):focus,
button:not(.s-btn):focus,
.button:focus,
a.button:focus,
a.button:visited:focus,
.btn:focus {
    border-color: #ea4a5a;
    box-shadow: none;
    background: #b03340;
    color: white !important;
}

.s-btn-group {
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.s-btn__muted.s-btn__outlined,
.s-btn__muted.s-btn__outlined:focus,
.s-btn__muted.s-btn__outlined.is-selected {
    color: #2f3337;
    border-color: #adb3b9;
    box-shadow: none;
}

.s-btn__muted.s-btn__outlined.is-selected {
    background-color: #eeeff1;
}

a,
.s-link,
.started .mod-flair,
.started a:not(.started-link),
.topbar-dialog a,
.topbar-dialog .related-links a {
    color: #ea4a5a;
}

a:hover,
.s-link:hover,
a.s-link__visited:hover,
.s-link.s-link__visited:hover,
a:active,
.s-link:active,
a.s-link__visited:active,
.s-link.s-link__visited:active,
.started .mod-flair:hover,
.started a:not(.started-link):hover,
.started-link:hover,
#sidebar .community-bulletin .bulletin-item-content a:hover,
.topbar-dialog a:visited,
.topbar-dialog.review-dialog .modal-content li > a:visited,
.topbar-dialog .related-links a:visited,
.topbar-dialog.help-dialog a:visited,
.topbar-dialog.siteSwitcher-dialog a:visited,
.topbar-dialog .header .-right a {
    color: #b03340 !important;
}

.mod-flair {
    color: #ea4a5a;
}

.bounty-indicator-tab {
    background-color: #ea4a5a;
}

.s-badge__bounty {
    background-color: #ea4a5a;
}

#tabs a.youarehere:before,
.tabs a.youarehere:before {
    background-color: #ea4a5a;
}

.page-numbers.current {
    background-color: #ea4a5a;
}

.subtabs a.youarehere,
.filter a.youarehere,
.subtabs a.active,
.filter a.active {
    border-color: #ea4a5a;
}

.subtabs a.youarehere,
.filter a.youarehere,
.subtabs a.active,
.filter a.active,
.subtabs a:hover,
.filter a:hover,
.subtabs a.youarehere:hover,
.filter a.youarehere:hover,
.subtabs a.active:hover,
.filter a.active:hover {
    border-color: #eeeff1;
}

.top-bar .indicator-badge._important {
    background-color: #ea4a5a;
}

.top-bar .-secondary .-link._danger-indicator:after {
    background: #ea4a5a;
}
```

If you want to get rid of those silly borders everywhere:

```
.flush-left {
    border: 0;
}

.question-summary {
    padding: 15px 10px;
    border: 0;
    border-radius: 3px;
    margin-left: 8px;
}

.subheader {
    border: 0;
}

.dashboard-item {
    padding: 15px 0;
    border-bottom: 0;
}

#question-header {
    border: 0;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
}

.comments {
    border: 0;
}

ul.comments-list .comment > * {
    border: 0;
    padding: 10px 0;
}
```

If you want all of these shenanigans plus some extras: download the FF code [here](https://1drv.ms/t/s!Aup3Ie22Dx2Eg4JI5b-Zce2HwEW09A) (for other uses, just delete the FF wrapper around the CSS)

Example of the homepage:

[image]
[Full size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ve8p7.png)

Example of the homepage with dark mode (external extension) turned on:

[image]
[Full size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gAMSf.png)

Comment: hero of the day...

Comment: just the day? ^_^

Comment: I added support for `ul`s and `ol`s.

Comment: I found [this question](https://superuser.com/a/191170/1816) useful for trying this out on Chrome. Have you tried using this custom styling on other sites around the network? If you find it generally useful, you might consider posting to Meta Stack Exchange so more people can benefit. (That said, I found the lack of horizontal rules in familiar places disorienting. Stockholm syndrome, I suppose. ;-)

Comment: Hi Jon, thanks for the follow-up. I mentioned in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/48004280#48004280) that I indeed used Stylus. But the _how_ is not really relevant for this answer. // I did not try it on different SE sites. Since a large part of this is bringing back our custom red colour, I don't think other sites will find much use in it. A possibility would be to use CSS variables to parametrise the colour, but support is [patchy](https://caniuse.com/#search=css%20var).

Comment: Also, I'm the first to admit getting rid of the borders was a personal preference more than a usability concern. That said, they do make the design very heavy.

Answer (score 0):

## YOU DON'T

It's here to stay

Comment: Thts fine the site operators can do whatever they want but thats not stopping us form making a theme that actually works.