# Can we get the old color back for our buttons?

Tags: feature-request, design

Would love if we could get the same color back for our buttons.

See [this post on meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/319675/358161) for reference.

[image]
[image]

Community; vote on answer below - no need to downvote.

Answer (score 8):

## YES

The old colors were much better, we would love our old colors back.

Comment: See [this answer](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3567/41100) for a user script

Answer (score 0):

## NO

The new colors are fine, we like the new look, no reason to change it.